# Develop correct structure and design pattern for my node project

Tags: node.js, api, design-patterns, model-view-controller

**Introduction**

> First time using Node and appreciate all help and improvements.

I have developed code that

1. first gets data from a post
2. secondly authenticates the API connection and gets the key
3. uses variables from the first and second function and posts to the API

**Question**

This code is all working and is node so back-end. However I have not built it with MVC in mind, I would like someone to help me clean this and structure it better.

I am brand new to node and wish for my first project to follow a neat MVC structure I can use as A idea on how to structure future products.

**What I have**

As said before the code works however it is all within `index.js` on the root, as it is the back-end of my application I would like it to be in a folder called `backend` then folders or files on from there.

**index.js**

```
//---------------------------------- Grab the packages we need and set variables ---------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var nodePardot = require('node-pardot');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Credential's for pardot API
var password = '######';
var userkey = '######';
var emailAdmin = '######';

// Start the server
app.listen(port);
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // support encoded bodies
console.log('Server started! At http://localhost:' + port); // Confirms server start

//---------------------------------- Function to get front end form posted data ----------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var firstFunction = function () {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve) { // may be redundant
        setTimeout(function () {
            app.post('/api/data', function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.body);
                // Get varibles from the post form
                var email_user = req.body.email;
                var first_name = req.body.fname;
                var last_name = req.body.lname;

                // res.send(email_user);
                res.send(first_name + ' ' + last_name + ' ' + email_user);

                //resolve when get the response
                resolve({
                    data_email: email_user,
                    data_first_name: first_name,
                    data_last_name: last_name
                });
            });

        }, 2000);
    });
    return promise;
};

//---------------------------------- Function to get API key from Pardot (AUTHENTICATION) ------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var secondFunction = function () {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            nodePardot.PardotAPI({
                userKey: userkey,
                email: emailAdmin,
                password: password,
                DEBUG: false
            }, function (err, client) {
                if (err) {
                    // Authentication failed
                    console.error("Authentication Failed", err);
                } else {
                    // Authentication successful
                    var api_key = client.apiKey;
                    console.log("Authentication successful !", api_key);
                    resolve({data_api: api_key});
                }
            });

        }, 2000);
    });
    return promise;
};

//---------------------------------- Function to post data to Pardot ---------------------------------------------------
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function thirdFunction(result) {
    var promise = new Promise(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            };

// Configure the request
            var useremail = result[0].data_email;
            var api = result[1].data_api;
            var Fname = result[0].data_first_name;
            var Lname = result[0].data_last_name;
            var options = {
                url: 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/create/email',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headers,
                form: {
                    'email': useremail,
                    'user_key': userkey,
                    'api_key': api,
                    'first_name': Fname,
                    'last_name': Lname
                }
            };

// Start the request
            request(options, function (error, response) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log("error", error);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Sent Data successful !");
                    console.log("API Key", api);
                    console.log("user", useremail);
                    console.log("userKey", userkey);
                    console.log("name", Fname);
                    console.log("surname", Lname);
                }
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
    return promise;
}

// sequence of functions
Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()])
    .then(thirdFunction);
```

Comment: To speak about design patterns first - you have to extract any objects / services as objects. Than try to find relations between extracted objects - no relations? No design patterns, sorry ...

Comment: No worries still trying to learn best way to structure the code and build future implementations